# Installing a BHO with Wix

Tags: installation, wix, bho

i just finished my Browser Helper Object and Im currently writing an installer for it.
so far i managed to get an MSI which copies the .dll to the desired location, but im not sure how i can register the object manually.
Which keys do I need to set so that the Internet Explorer loads the BHO automatically?

Comment: If you finished your BHO, you tested it, right? You need to add the same entries into the registry that you added to test it.

Comment: but while testint i used "regsvr32.exe /i BHO.dll" to test it, I dont know, which keys i need to set in the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When use `regsrv32` to register the DLL, it calls [`DllRegisterServer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682162%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your DLL to perform the registration. So you have to add all the keys and values this function (`DllRegisterServer`) writes to the registry to your MSI, so that MSI writes them for you during installation.

To unregister the DLL, you use `regsrv32 /u`, in this case [`DllUnregisterServer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is called in the DLL. Usually it just removes the entries added in `DllRegisterServer`.

Windows Installer will automatically remove all the added registry entries when it's uninstalled. Just check `DllUnregisterServer` does not perform any other actions. If it does, implement it in WiX.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I made a registry snapshot before and after registring so i could easily figure out which keys i need to set.

Comment: @Horstinator I would have thought that reading the source code for your `DllRegisterServer` and `DllUnregisterServer` is *much easier* than getting registry snapshots and then comparing them.